# Limit image proportions as inline attachment in c# constructed email

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook-2013

Good day,

How can I reduce / limit the size of an image as an inline attachment in a c# email? The image that appears on the email is physically HUGE, and I want to scale it down to around 475px x 475px.

HTML:

```
...
                    <td style="max-width: 475px; max-height: 475px">
                        <img style="width:475px; height: 475px;" id="Img1" src="cid:Product" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 475px">
                        <div class="jamHeader">
                            <img id="jamHeaderImage" src="cid:Header" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="labelContainer">
                            <h1 class="title-block">
                                <p id="SoftwareName">"xxxxxxxxxx"</p>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="productInfo">
                                <div id="EmailDescription">
                                    xxxxxxxxxx 
                                    This link expires in 24 hours if not redeemed."
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
...
```

Code to attach image

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productImage))
    {
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment product = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(productImage);
        product.ContentId = "Product";
        product.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        product.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
        message.Attachments.Add(product);
    }
```

As seen on [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) site, the `max-width` and `max-height` css styles are no longer supported in Outlook 2007 up. The images are read from the disk, added as an attachment and given a content ID which matches the content ID placeholder image tag on the html page. The image doesn't resize to smaller proportions, and... its scaring the other elements on the page by making them feel really...really tiny.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Did you try <img width="475" height="475" ... > ?

Comment: yeah, no good. the height property is not supported in outlook 2007 up. at all. never mind max-height or min-height

Comment: You should not use any css in emails as many clients don't support it. Try to imagine it's 1999 when constructing your email content!

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I have ... a very picky client that wants very fancy emails. this is my last obstacle, all the CSS is fine, except for this email's image size

Comment: I think the only thing that can be done is to open the image in c#, using `System.Drawing` Classes, check the proportions, if it is larger than the size I want, programatically re-size the image, save it back to disk, read newly created image.  but is there a shorter way?

Comment: Are you sure that the suggestion from @Loathing doesn't work? He said to use html attributes and not CSS, that should work for some clients.

Comment: I've also used https://litmus.com/ which is great for seeing how emails look in various clients. It's not free though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with this problem. Real problem is you are using not **Embedded IE** in Outlook, but **Word rendering engine**. It has more quirks then IE6 and IE7 combined. I solved the problem by **scaling the image in server** and using it.

Answer (score 0):

Huge workaround, but this is both a response and answer to what @Margus was getting to.

Scale the image on the server: Code I used-

```
private void ResizeImage(string path)
{
    var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    var widthAndHeightMax = 375D; //375px by 375 px. 
    var resizeImagePath = string.Concat(path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\')), "\\Resized");
    var newImageName = path.Remove(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    var newImageFullPath = string.Concat(resizeImagePath, "\\", newImageName);
    if (image.Width > widthAndHeightMax || image.Height > widthAndHeightMax || !File.Exists(newImageFullPath))
    {
        //Get Image Ratio
        var ratioX = widthAndHeightMax / image.Width;
        var ratioY = widthAndHeightMax / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
        var newImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var resizedImage = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
        resizedImage.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        resizedImage.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        resizedImage.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        if (!Directory.Exists(resizeImagePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(resizeImagePath);
        }
        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
        var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().SingleOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);

        // Create an Encoder object for the Quality parameter.
        var encoder = Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Save the image as a JPEG file with quality level.
        var encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 100L);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;

        //newImage.Save(newImageFullPath, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters); throws GDI+ general error. normally security related
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(string.Concat(resizeImagePath, "\\", newImageName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    newImage.Save(ms, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //If the image exists, it may already be used by another process (which means it exists)
            }
        }
        productImage = newImageFullPath;
    }
}
```